# Unexpected behavior of code inside $(document).ready() -- Should it get executed sequentially?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, document-ready, ready

I have been using JavaScript and jQuery for a while now. But I still haven't fully grasped how it all works. I profusely apologize if my question is redundant, incomprehensible and/or plain stupid.

I am using [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) in combination with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (no plugins, just plain jQuery) to populate a `div#googleMap` with map of London. In addition to that, I'm trying to write a function to get coordinates of a given address ([Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)). What I'm going to do with those coordinates is a different story.

My problem lies with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  mapObject   = initGoogleMaps();
  coordinates = getCoordinates('United Kingdom');

  console.log(coordinates.toString());

  function initGoogleMaps() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    map = new google.maps.Map($("#googleMap")[0], {
      center:            new google.maps.LatLng(51.511214, -0.119824),
      zoom:                     10,
      heading:                  0,
      mapTypeId:                google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI:         true,
      disableDoubleClickZoom:   true,
      draggable:                false,
      keyboardShortcuts:        false,
      scrollwheel:              false,
      backgroundColor:          'transparent'
    });
    return map;
  }

  function getCoordinates(address) {
    fallback    = 'London, United Kingdom';
    geocoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    address     = typeof(address) == 'string' ? address : fallback;
    coordinates = '';

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address':address },
                     function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        coordinates = results[0].geometry.location;
      } else {
        coordinates = 'Location: "' + address + '" not found.\n' +
                      'Status: ' + status;
      }
    });

    return coordinates;
  }
}); // jQuery(document)
```

I'm using [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), more specifically, the [Javascript Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) built into Google Chrome.

When I refresh the page, the output I get is this:

```
Coordinates: ↩
```

I thought maybe the `Maps API` is unsuccessful in Geocoding the location. But...

1. That would print a message: `Location "London Heathrow" not found.`
2. I declared `coordinates` outside `$.ready()` and in the console, after the empty message had been printed, typed `coordinates`, pressed return and it gave me: `coordinates ▸` *`M {jb: 55.378051, kb: -3.43597299999999, toString: function, b: function, equals: function…}`*

Which is odd. In my perception, the `coordinates` identifier has been assigned an empty string (`''`) value. Why? I called the `getCoordinates()` function right before I used `coordinates` identifier.

Could it possibly be that the instructions inside `$(document).ready(function(){...})` do not get executed in any particular order? Or is it because of the delay while fetching `results` through the Maps API? How do I get the `console.log(...)` instruction only after the value of `coordinates` has been fetched and assigned?

Maybe it's some stupid mistake I'm overlooking.

Comment: @geocodezip : I apologize. I kept thinking of it as a problem with jQuery rather than a problem with `geocode`. I did a thorough Google search, I swear. But I think my search terms were entirely wrong.

By the way, is there a way to return the results?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment `The geocoder is asynchronous, you can **use** the results in the callback function, you can't return them from it.`

Comment: I read that. I thought there would be some other way to return the data, to be used by some other function outside of `getCoordinates()` scope. I gather there isn't. Terribly sorry for appearing to be a dimwit.

Answer (score 0):

Your `coordinates = '';` is out of scope with the `.geocode` callback function. You need `var coordinates = '';` instead.

Comment: @dfocker I can understand how it can be out of scope. But I don't understand how `var` should solve that problem. I did, however, try that solution anyway. But that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: `var` pulls whatever variable you call it on into the scope of the block it is in. So the `coordinates` variable would be the same variable inside the callback function as outside the callback. But my answer isn't completely right, geocodezip was correct in that it's asynchronous and you can't return the value it gives you.

Comment: Regardless of the original question, what you just explained was unknown to me. Maybe out of context, but it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, I would recommend looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for more/better info.